# Re-execution of for loop when exception occured from current position in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop, exception

I want to do something like shown below for my project.

## whenever any exception will occur I want to start the for loop from current position of 'i'

for eg:
if exception occured at i=3 then my for statement should again start from i=3 till end

Example

```
for i in range(5):
    try:
        # some code
    except Exception as e:
        restart_for_loop_from_current i
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: How does this avoid infinite attempts to redo the failed `i = 3` process?

Comment: i will check the count of exception and if it exceeds the limit then exit

Comment: I am no expert but I think this is a bad way looping if you are going to continue the loop. Maybe you might use `yield` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a nested loop. Something like this would work:

```
for i in range(5):
    loop = True
    while loop:
        try:
            # some code
            loop = False
        except Exception as e:
            # some code make sure this while loop is not endless
            pass
```

Comment: Then loop will still be True, and effectively you will try the code again with the same value for i as you requested. The while loop will only stop if loop = False is reached, thus if there is no exception. Then the next i will be handled.

Answer (score 2):

Why not change the for-loop to a while-loop? Just increment the variable when no exception occurred, something like this:

```
while i < 5:
    try:
        # loop operations
        i = i + 1
    except:
        error = error + 1
        # error handling code
```

Comment: You increase the error count and `i` remains the actual value, so you will try again next loop, until the error count reach the value you want, so you can break the loop.